# DMS - On Going Replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I am planning to replicate data using DMS between our on-prem db and cloud db. The cloud db will have the data for performing analytics. The DBs are hetrogeneous. Can I do an on-going replication between the on-prem and cloud dbs using DMS? Will the replication be near real time? Will it cause any performance impacts to the on-prem db which is accessed by other applications? I am assuming the applications need not be shutdown while the data is being migrated.

Answer (score 0):

1. DMS Supports Heterogeneous migration. However, for better information, you need to specify your DBMS. Furthermore, when DMS transfer data into your cloud db, the data will be in cloud db but schema will not be guaranteed.
2. DMS with On-going option has impact to source db but it's not big impact. It will be like a few more connections to your source db. With 'on-going' option, application doesn't need to be shutdown.